# How to remember the last window size?

Tags: window-management

I really like elementary OS but I'm missing one important thing for me:

When adjusting and closing windows, is there any possibility in elementary to remember the last window size and position?

Answer (score 4):

Ahhh sorry, I was already able to find the solution. As long as I disable the setting that windows do not get maximized when its above 70%, the last size is now remembered !!

Solution:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false
```